# How to select distinct rows without using group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

```
A B C
1 1 1 
1 1 1 
2 2 2 
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 
4 4 4 
5 5 5 
5 5 5 
5 5 5 
6 6 6
6 6 6
```

I am to output only the distinct rows without using the group by statement. I cannot use group by because it makes mysql hang. So it should return

```
1 1 1
2 2 2 
3 3 3 
4 4 4 
5 5 5 
6 6 6
```

I am using DISTINCT in for an inner join.This does not work either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLEA inner join TABLEB on TABLEA.A = TABLEB.A
```

Comment: "I cannot use group by because it makes mysql hang." Uhhh..... someone has a lock maybe? If `GROUP BY` isn't working, you should try to find out why. It's unlikely that trying different queries will solve the problem.

Comment: No locks based on my processlist. I am not sure why.

Comment: How many rows are there in your real table? Can you show us the query that's making MySQL hang?

Comment: @cool_cs: Maybe your database is corrupt or something. There's no reason why GROUP BY shouldn't work here (using DISTINCT is a more concise solution, but it won't solve your problem).

Comment: Have you tried SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C FROM TABLEA inner join TABLEB on TABLEA.A = TABLEB.A ; ? This should do the trick according to the documentation. Cf my answer. DISTINCT A,B,C is not the same as DISTINCT *

Comment: If the `GROUP BY` makes MySQL hang, then you have a bigger issue that should be addressed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C FROM TABLE;
```

According to mysql documentation, DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

I created a sample on jsfiddle and it works IMHO

```
create table tablea (A int,B int,C int);
create table tableb (A int);

INSERT INTO tablea VALUES (1,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(3,3,3),(4,4,4),(4,4,4),(5,5,5),(5,5,5),(5,5,5),(6,6,6),(6,6,6);
INSERT INTO tableb VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1);

SELECT DISTINCT tablea.A,tablea.B,tablea.C FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.A=tableb.A;
```

feel free to experiment on this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f767/3/2).

Comment: I try that and I still get duplicate rows

Comment: do you have other columns or are A, B and C the only columns as I understood for my answer ?

Comment: I do select distinct * from table and I get the same rows as original

Comment: how many columns do you have ? If you have a column with a uniqueID then it is normal that SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE gives you all the original rows. Please clarify this in your question.

Comment: I have like 10 columns but I am using distinct with an inner join. The distinct works for a single table but not for an inner join of two tables. So SELECT distinct * from tableA inner join tableB... does not work

Answer (score 10):

[**This may totally shock you but MySQL uses GROUP BY under the hood to execute DISTINCT !!!**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html)

Here is something you may want to try

If the table is called `mytable`, do these two things:

First run this

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD INDEX ABC (A,B,C);`
```

Second, run this query

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM mytable GROUP BY A,B,C;
```

### GROUP BY actually works better with an index present !!!

Here is sample code to prove it works

```
mysql> drop database if exists cool_cs;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> create database cool_cs;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> use cool_cs
Database changed
mysql> create table mytable
    -> (A int,B int,C int, key ABC (A,B,C));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> INSERt INTO mytable VALUES
    -> (1,1,1),(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),
    -> (3,3,3),(4,4,4),(4,4,4),(5,5,5),(5,5,5),
    -> (5,5,5),(6,6,6),(6,6,6);
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select a,b,c FROM mytable group by a,b,c;
+------+------+------+
| a    | b    | c    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    3 |    3 |
|    4 |    4 |    4 |
|    5 |    5 |    5 |
|    6 |    6 |    6 |
+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: It still hangs when I add an index.

Comment: Three questions for you : 1) How many rows does your table have? 2) When you say `distinct row`, do you literally mean all columns or just one column? 3) Mai we please see the CREATE TABLE statement for your current table?

Answer (score 2):

the DISTINCT keyword does what you want. I.e., if the name of your table is A, `select distinct * from A` will do the trick.

Cf. mysql manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 2):

IF you (or anyone else) really wants to get distinct resutl without using DISTINCT or GROUP BY statement, this may be the way:

```
SELECT
    a.name
FROM person a
LEFT JOIN person b
    ON (a.name = b.name OR (a.name IS NULL AND b.name IS NULL))
    AND a.id < b.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

It's rather a quaint thing, though.